# Rails - Create parent and child at the same time in has_one belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, belongs-to, has-one

I'm sur I do it wrong, but I can't see where.
I've got this two models :

**Subscription.rb (child)**

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :state, :subscriber_id, :subscriber_type, :last_payment

  belongs_to :subscriber, polymorphic: true

  validates :subscriber_id, presence: true
  validates :subscriber_type, presence: true
end
```

**restorer.rb (Parent)**

```
class Restorer < User
  attr_accessible :firstname, :lastname, :restaurant_attributes, :subscription_attributes

  has_one :restaurant, dependent: :destroy, :autosave => true
  has_one :subscription, as: :subscriber, :autosave => true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :restaurant
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subscription

end
```

When I want two create a new restorer, and a new subscription (at the same time)
It doesn't work :

```
  def create
    @restorer = Restorer.create params[:restorer]
    @restaurant = @restorer.build_restaurant params[:restorer][:restaurant_attributes]
    @subscription = @restorer.build_subscription params[:restorer][:subscription_attributes]

    if @restorer.save
      ...
    else
      ...
    end
  end
```

Comment: if you use `save` you sould replace `create` to `new`, also you don't need use `build_..` manualy(it should work automaticaly) and try `save!` which raise message if something is wrong.

Comment: it raise a record_invalid error... seems with this error 'subscriber_id should not be blank'

Comment: This is because you cannot validate the presence of `id` for `nested_attributes` as these are in essence be created almost `asynchronously` no `id` will be present on the save until after save completes. If you truely must validate this which I don't feel you do with nested attributes then you would have to create these objects in a step through procedure e.g. create subscriber then create the associations. You may be able to handle this in a transaction but I have little experience with this.

Comment: Ok, how can I validate the presence of child ?

Comment: I could explain this but [This Blog Post](http://homeonrails.com/2012/10/validating-nested-associations-in-rails/) does it much more concisely than I could on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the comments and your code, it looks like the reason it isn't working is because of the validations on `Subscriber`.  `Restorer` has one `Subscription` and `Subscription` belongs to a `Subscriber`. Nowhere are you creating the subscriber, hence why the subscription is failing it's validation. You need to either remove the validations, or set those validated properties (subscriber_id and subscriber_type) on `Subscriber`.

It's kinda a bit gross what you are trying to do in your create, but it should look something like this if you are going to do it that way:

```
def create
  @restorer = Restorer.create params[:restorer]

  # These two lines aren't needed if you are accepting nested attributes
  @restaurant = @restorer.build_restaurant params[:restorer][:restaurant_attributes]
  @subscription = @restorer.build_subscription params[:restorer][:subscription_attributes]

  subscriber = Subscriber.new params[:subscriber]
  @subscription.subscriber = subscriber

  if @restorer.save
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

Btw, its better to validate the relationship `subscriber` rather than the id `subscriber_id`:

```
validates :subscriber, presence: true
```