# How to inizialize a model when you set another model in a form in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model `User` and a model `UserAditionalDatum`. `UserAditionalDatum` has a `User_id` attribute. When I create a new `User`, I need to initialize the `UserAditionalDatum` just with the `User_id` number and anything else. It would be like a dependent between models but instead of destroy the data to create it.

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :UserAditionalDatum, dependent: :destroy
end
```

user_aditional_datum.rb:

```
class LibrRelAmigo < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :libr_usuario
end
```

Comment: You've put the same code for both models, and your `has_many`s are very peculiar, so based on that and your question, I think you need to read the [ActiveRecord Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) guide, and maybe the other ActiveRecord guides too.

Comment: I believe that http://stackoverflow.com/q/25745498/631619 will show you a way

Comment: Do you need to populate any attributes besides user_id when initially creating the UserAditionalDatum model?

Comment: @Infused I need just the user_id. Others atributes will be add in others transactions.